# Swift UITableView separator not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, separator

I'm new in ios/swft and faced with problem showing separator in table view.
I've spent already few days tried out almost all suggestions none of them works for me.
I'm inserting cells dynamically and in this case separator disappears.
Below the code I'm using.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let tableData = ["One","Two","Three"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")!

        cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

On a storyboard it is simple tableview on a view, nothing special.

This is really annoying me, please help to fix it.

Comment: add a link to a screenshot of what you see...

Comment: [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w305a6pta3zwkkt/Screenshot%202016-02-02%2014.49.43.png?dl=0)

Comment: you have a custom cell in your storyboard, did you add your own label to the cell? What frame & constraints does it have?

Comment: [tableview_with_contraints](https://www.dropbox.com/s/imdgpfchv256k4i/Screenshot%202016-02-02%2015.08.42.png?dl=0)

[cell_with_contraints](https://www.dropbox.com/s/690j151dr2m4mea/Screenshot%202016-02-02%2015.09.53.png?dl=0)

Comment: [cell_frame](https://www.dropbox.com/s/276mjdpeonluj9y/Screenshot%202016-02-02%2015.10.51.png?dl=0)

Comment: it's the stuff inside the content view that's important

Comment: [content-view](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wbwwlz531f6dy83/Screenshot%202016-02-02%2015.43.02.png?dl=0)

[content-view-frame](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3p4yhmnvbhjxp2j/Screenshot%202016-02-02%2015.43.41.png?dl=0)

Comment: it actually looks fine because you aren't adding your own subviews. use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` to dequeue the cell instead

Comment: thanks for have a look, I changed but it is still not visible :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turned out that issue is only on the simulator, not on an actual device.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.grayColor()
}
```

If this doesn't work, you should edit your question to show (the code of) **HOW** you are inserting new cells into your table.

Comment: I don't get what to show, as I posted all the code in my view controller.
This is SingleViewApplication and all code posted is in the default created ViewController.
As I said in storyboard nothing changed except cell Accessory type, put it as "Disclosure Indicator"

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late but may be help someone in Swift 4:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.singleLine
tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.YourColor
tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)
}
```

Comment: Note that 'UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.singleLine' has been renamed to 'UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.singleLine' and 'UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)' has been renamed to UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)'